# Options to communicate with barcode scanner from website

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner

I'm starting to design a website and one of the desired requirements is to be able to plug a barcode scanner into a PC and being able to scan barcodes and interact with the website.  I'm wondering, what are some of the popular options (maybe a Javascript library) for a website to interact with a scanner on a client PC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**What kind of Barcode scanner?**

If it's a simple cheap one that plugs in via USB, then all the scanner does is rapidly enter the value of code it scanned via keyboard commands. This is why you can open notepad or excel, scan something and the string will show up on in the document. In this scenario you'll need to write some logic in javascript to capture keyboard events and identify rapid entries in order to separate user input from scanner input.  Almost all front end frameworks have a keyboard events library you can leverage

- [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/)
- [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)
- [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

If it's a more advanced scanner that is networked or broadcasts through a socket/COM port, you'll want to open up socket/serial port to it over the network, or directly through the PC serial and then through a local server relay. Then simply capture the scanned events as they are broadcasted for the listening webpage to use.

- [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)
- [HTML 5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)
- [Websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

**Edits:** to reflect comments

Comment: The scanners generally communicate through a COM port (via emulation), so I really don't think a keyboard capture event would apply.  The raw data (when using the scanners in a Windows application) seems to come in a byte array format.

Comment: Then you'll want to use a serial port library, like serialport for Nodejs to listen to the scanner. Then you'll need to build a websocket server to relay the com port event, so the web app can "listen" through the websocket to the scanner - ideally by usings some of the links mentioned above in my second part